# How to split semi colon delimited column value into rows in python?

Tags: python, split

I have a spreadsheet with the following data. The last column contains semicolon delimited value, which I want to transpose into multiple rows, while duplicating the values for first three columns.

```
   A,B,C,1
   D,E,F,1;2;3
   G,H,I,1;2
```

I want the output to be :

```
   A,B,C,1
   D,E,F,1
   D,E,F,2
   D,E,F,3
   G,H,I,1
   G,H,I,2
```

How do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Where can we be of assistance?

Comment: Also - could you be more specific on the input format? I.e. I understand you have spreadsheet, but then you somehow have this data in python - how ? pandas/list/rdd ?

Comment: I have converted the spreadsheet data into csv file and loaded into a hive table. Only option is to use either hive or pyspark to create the output and write it back to another table. I am finding it difficult to do this in hive, hence asking for help with pyspark, not very well versed with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just go by what you have provided.

```
my_str = """A,B,C,1
D,E,F,1;2;3
G,H,I,1;2"""
```

I first split 'my_str' based on new line character and then semi-colon - i.e,

```
my_list = [strn.split(';') for strn in my_str.split('\n')]
```

Now my_list will look something like,

```
[['A,B,C,1'], ['D,E,F,1', '2', '3'], ['G,H,I,1', '2']]
```

This might not be the most elegant solution,

```
for i, sub_list in enumerate(my_list):
    if len(sub_list) > 1:
        for j in range(1, len(sub_list)):
            my_list[i][j] = my_list[i][0][:-1] + my_list[i][j]
```

Finally, my_list will look like:

```
[['A,B,C,1'], ['D,E,F,1', 'D,E,F,2', 'D,E,F,3'], ['G,H,I,1', 'G,H,I,2']]
```

And then, just print it out. For example

```
for sub_list in my_list:
    for strn in sub_list:
        print(strn)
```

You get the desired answer

```
A,B,C,1
D,E,F,1
D,E,F,2
D,E,F,3
G,H,I,1
G,H,I,2
```

Edit to write this output to a file:

```
with open('new_test_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for sub_list in my_list:
        for strn in sub_list:
            f.write(strn+'\n')
```

Comment: great it is working as expected. Just one question, how do I write the output back to a file?

Comment: Edited my answer. If this was what you were looking for, please accept.